# Django Admin page models name instead of TABLE object(id)

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-admin

Is there any way to change the way objects are named in Django Admin page. Currently all of the objects are using a TABLE Object(id) as their name:

[table in admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3f4z.png)

Can i make it for example a key form the table like a name or smth. And is there any way to add search bar that goes over the names of the items in the table to filter it by that name.

Comment: define __str__ method in your Model https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__str__

Answer (score 3):

Try this inside your model:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name # this 'name' field must be exist in your model.
```

For search bar and other things you should read django documentation below:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: Due to the fact my data from the database is using uft8m4. If i do it like this the website crashes and gives OperationError when i try to add an object or edit existing one . The "name" is with cyrillic.